# How to access private member variables in C#?

Tags: c#, variables, private, member

I am trying to access the member variable Name, which I set it as a private member variable, to be displayed as an output. Please don't worry about why I set the member variable Name up as private. It's only for practice purposes.

Basically my output is to display a name on the shell. Either

> My name is Sora

or

> My name is Xehanort

Right now the code displays

> My name is [BLANK]

I'd like to know the two ways of doing it. The first is via user input, and the second is when the name of the character is stored in the program variables.
Now I know how to do it both ways but that is when my member variables are public, but not as private. I'd like to do it as private but I'm stumped.

These are my codes so far. The first one is the Character class...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CSharp_Practice
{
    class Character
    {
        private string Name;
        private int Age;
        private char Gender;
        private float Height { get; set; }
        private float Weight { get; set; }
        private string Nationality { get; set; }
        private string Appearance { get; set; }


    //SET AND GET NAME
        public void setName(string name)
        {
            this.Name = name;
        }

        public string getName()
        {
            return Name;
        }

    //SET AND GET AGE
        public void setAge(int age)
        {
            this.Age = age;
        }

        public int getAge()
        {
            return Age;
        }
    }

}
```

...and the second one is the main program.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CSharp_Practice
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Character Hero = new Character();
            Character Villain = new Character();


            //List of Heroes
            Hero.getName();

            //           Hero.Name = "Sora";
            //           Hero.Age = 19;

            //        Villain.Name = "Xehanort";
            //        Villain.Age = 79;

            Console.WriteLine("My name is " + Hero.getName());
        }
    }
}
```

Please let me know how I can do this, or if it's not possible, let me know why also. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a `string` value with a name you wish to set, you should be able to use `Hero.setName(value)` rather than `Hero.Name = value`.

This applies to both console input AND hardcoded variables.

Comment: Ah, nice! Thanks! :D